# Targeting specific elements inside an element with javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I do the below with javascript?

`$("div.details.counter span")`

I can use `ID's` but I'm curious how we can do the above jQuery style of getting stuff with pure javascript.

Comment: [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

Comment: I am not familiar with jQuery. Could you please explain what the above expression does?

Comment: @KeyurGolani it targets all the `span` tags inside all the `div` tags that have a class of both `details` and `counter`

Comment: @Deadpool "inside" i hope means "inside the DOM subtree of". I would describe that selector as targetting all the `span` elements which have a `div` ancestor with both `details` and `counter` class. To avoid confusion regarding the child selector.

Comment: @Tibos what did you expect. It was translated by deadpool ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution with pure javascript for most selectors supported by jQuery is to use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
document.querySelectorAll("div.details.counter span")
```

If you don't have support for `querySelectorAll` in your browser of choice, you could take a look at jQuery's implementation of the [selector engine](http://sizzlejs.com/) to see how it matches various parts of the selector.